# Determine if file HANDLE is a pipe handle

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, handle

In a particular function, I'm receiving a file `HANDLE`, and I want to check if this file handle is of real disk file handle and not of a pipe handle. It is guaranteed that it would be either disk-file handle, or it might be pipe handle and not any other type of handle.

How can I do it?

```
void ProcessHandle(HANDLE hFile)
{
       // Process only if disk file handle
}
```

The function [GetFileInformationByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952(v=vs.85).aspx) would retrieve file handle information, and would fail if the handle is a pipe handle, as documented:

> This handle should not be a pipe handle.

However, it requires a large structure (`BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION`) and would fill the information. I am not looking for this detailed information, so using this function is a performance hit.

Comment: From a quick look, that structure is 13 dwords; the impact of copying 52 bytes around is negligible compared even just to the syscall overhead. Unless you have hard data that proves that this is your bottleneck, you are *way* overthinking this issue.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, So in your opinion 52 bytes won't be a performance hit? As compared to simple API that doesn't this huge parameter? It would waste stack size, plus the pointer-size argument has to be pushed to the stack. I'm not calling it just once, but umpteen times.

Comment: It's a syscall. That's order of magnitudes more intensive than copying a few bytes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't understand it. Is `GetFileType` not needing a big parameter (not by itself though), *not* a syscall? A syscall with 52 bytes of stack vs. another syscall with just a handle - which is better? I didn't say I don't/can't use a syscall. I asked a lighter approach.

Comment: If you don't like consulting an oracle then just don't.  Add a `BOOL isfile` argument.  You can't know but the caller can know.

Comment: @Ajay: stack size = free, unless you overflow it; your `sub esp, something` at the start of the function will become `sub esp, something_bigger`, which cost exactly the same; pushing a pointer-size argument on the stack = a handful of cycles (the top of the stack is virtually always in cache), the same whatever pointer-sized argument we are talking about; performing a syscall = 1000+ cycles at best. We are talking about 2-3 orders of magnitude of difference.

Comment: Then of course there's the cost on the kernel side of performing the actual job - a failure is probably going to be fast, but as always, you can't know for sure unless you measure - and compare it with your alternatives. If you need to know that information, you can only ask to the caller (who actually created that handle) or to the kernel (which is the only one who stores that information), and the only way in this last case is a syscall. If you need to check this information so often and is always on the same handles maybe you can add some caching to speed it up if it's a problem?

Comment: Also, FYI: http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/; notice where the syscall is, and that the horizontal scale is logarithmic.

Comment: @Ajay Where is your evidence that passing a few bytes on the stack is a bottleneck for your program?

Comment: `GetFileInformationByHandle` is return true for pipe file handle too. so you nothing determinate in this way. the `GetFileType` is really the best for this job. this api internal call [`ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567070(v=vs.85).aspx) with *FileFsDeviceInformation* - in [`FILE_FS_DEVICE_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545788(v=vs.85).aspx) in this case will be `DeviceType == FILE_DEVICE_NAMED_PIPE`

Comment: @HansPassant, I simplified the problem to post it as a question on SO. No, the caller doesn't know. This function would determine (the bool) if it is pipe handle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, when did I say that? Both functions are taking a just pointer-size argument. My point is just about 52-additional bytes on the stack that the user side program has to create, and the kernel side has to fill. I can't make it global or static, it will need stack memory, and would take time/space as compared to no-data (0 bytes). IMO `GetFileType` is cheaper as compared to GFIBH. There is no need to disagree on this!

Comment: `I don't/can't use a syscall. I asked a lighter approach` - without go to kernel so called `syscall` - you can not got information. `GetFileInformationByHandle` return true for any pipe handle too, it not fail in this case - so it not a solution at all - nothing to discuss really

Comment: @RbMm, You are missing the "I *didn't* say..." part. Why is everybody debating? :)

Comment: @Ajay It's rather pointless arguing about performance without measuring. Perhaps there are other factors that you don't know about that make the variant that copies data to the stack faster than the alternative. Don't second guess on performance. Measure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest API call for this is [`GetFileType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364960.aspx). Pass your handle and compare the return value with `FILE_TYPE_DISK` and `FILE_TYPE_PIPE`.

However, I very much doubt that there will be a measurable performance difference between the alternative you mention in your question. Don't assume that calling `GetFileInformationByHandle` will be slower. Check first by profiling.

Of course, your use of `GetFileInformationByHandle` is a somewhat roundabout way to infer the type of the file. There is a good argument that `GetFileType` is a better choice since it gets the information you need directly. Indeed, as discussed in various comments, it appears that `GetFileInformationByHandle` does not meet your needs functionally. So, use `GetFileType`.

Comment: My only concern about `GetFileInformationByHandle` is that he's relying on a failure that isn't strictly contractual - the documentation says that "This handle should not be a pipe handle.", which means that no well formed program should ever even try to pass a pipe handle. Tomorrow they may extend the function to make it work even for pipes, and that wouldn't break the contract (but would break OP's program). `GetFileType` seems a way better way (most importantly, way clearer in its intent).

Comment: @matteo that's a good point and one that I hadn't originally hauled on board. It is also worth encouraging the asker to measure performance rather than assume what it will be.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - `GetFileInformationByHandle` work for pipe handles just now. it not failure in this case

Comment: @RbMm: if that's the case, it's even worse, that method just cannot work to discriminate between file and pipes.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - you can very easy check this yourself `if (CreatePipe(&r,&w, 0,0)) { GetFileInformationByHandle(r, &bhfi); CloseHandle(r); CloseHandle(w);}` however David give really the best solution - `GetFileType`